# Subview and UIWebView UIGesture doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, uigesturerecognizer, subview

I recently got into trouble with a View Controller which has a UIWebView in it and a subview which I would like to add to the View Controller.

That's the View with the UIWebView:
http://cl.ly/image/03473l0e3a2L

My target is, to add a Share Menu which does work without problems:
http://cl.ly/image/3b273t2o3P00

But now I have the problem, that I set gesture recognizers for the social icons + labels (twitter,facebook,mail) - but these gesture recognizers don't do anything.

The ShareView is a UIView Subclass and I add the Gesture Recognizers this way:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *fbTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fbTapped:)];
fbTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
fbTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
fbTap.delegate = self;
[fbImage addGestureRecognizer:fbTap];
[fbLabel addGestureRecognizer:fbTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *twTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twTapped:)];
twTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
twTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
twTap.delegate = self;
[twImage addGestureRecognizer:twTap];
[twLabel addGestureRecognizer:twTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *mailTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mailTapped:)];
mailTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
mailTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
mailTap.delegate = self;
[mailImage addGestureRecognizer:mailTap];
[mailLabel addGestureRecognizer:mailTap];
```

I think the Label and the UIImageView names do explain themselves. Every Label and ImageView has set userInteractionEnabled to YES. The ShareView is also enabled for Userinteractions and I did set UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to it.

The fbTapped,mailTapped and twTapped functions do send a Notification to the Main View (the view which has the webview and the ShareView in it).

But now when I click on the labels or imageviews, nothing happendes.

I did read on stackoverflow that the UIWebView in the MainView could interrupt the recognization? But I don't know how to solve this problem.

Would be really happy If you could help me or point me into the right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of code will point you to the right direction:
1.Add a gesture recognizer delegate :

```
  @interface myclass <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

{

```
   //Whatever you are doing with gestures
```

}

2.Implement the delegate method:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer      shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

{
    //Do your stuff

```
 return YES;
```

}

check if the control reaches this delegate